# Docker Container not able to access in localhost and also same network segment

Tags: docker, nginx, containers

New to docker, please correct my statement
I'm trying to access docker container ex:nginx web server using port 80 in docker engine machine but am unable to access it.

Here my docker Engine network 10.20.20.0/24.

Docker Engine IP :  10.20.20.3

```
> Telnet 10.20.20.3 80  Connection failed
    tcp        0      0 10.20.20.3:80       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28953/docker-proxy
```

Docker Container IP : 172.18.0.4

```
> Telnet 172.18.0.4 80  Connection success
```

Docker network detail

```
[root@xxxxxxxxx]# docker network inspect 1984f08c739d [
    {
        "Name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Id": "1984f08c739d6d6fc6b4769e877714844b9e57ca680f61edf3a528bd12ca5ad1",
        "Created": "2021-11-13T21:01:27.53591809+05:30",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "126d5128621fa6cde0389f4c6e0b53be36670bce5f62e981da6e17722b88c4a9": {
                "Name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "EndpointID": "b011052062ae137e3d190032311e0fbc5850f0459c9b24d8cc1d315a9dc18773",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "xxxxxxxx",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2"
        }
    } ]
```

I can access these nginx in other networks like 10.20.21.0/24 so on. But not on the same network 10.20.20.0/24 or same docker engine running on it.

Comment: What are those various networks; where do they come from?  In general the IP addresses that get shown in places like `docker network inspect` are private to Docker and you can't access them from other hosts (or in most cases from outside Docker at all).  How did you launch the container, how are you trying to connect to it, and from where?

Comment: Container running on default bridge network.
Here my docker compose file for mongo db

"
version: '3.1'
services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4.8
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /opt/db:/data/db
      - /opt/configdb:/data/configdb
    ports:
      - "10.20.20.3:27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: XXXXXXXXX"

Comment: Docker engine  VM having two separate interfaces eth0 and eth1. I need to configure it with eth1 10.20.20.3 with containers traffic and send receive via eth1. @David Maze

Answer (score 0):

My Environment Docker Engine VM  having 2 Interfaces i.e. eth0 and eth1 with different subnet. In Previously it'll not work because both interfaces having separate routing table in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts (route-eth0,route-eth1 and rule-eth0,eth1) Base hyper-v AHV. These route written to persistent interface. I tried to removing route for eth0. Since eth0 doesnt required routing table to persistent, it'll come by default route table in Linux. Then restarted the network..Hola there we go the docker listening on eth0 interfaces and something did for eth1. it's worked. Both eth0 and eth1 interfaces I can map to the dockers network. It's work like charm. I believe in AHV doesnt not required routing table for AHV VMs for different and same network subnets. So here the concluded its routing issues. Issues was resolved, I can access docker container with eth0,eth1 interfaces across different subnets and same subnet.

Both interfaces worked after restarting without any routes in AHV VMs and power off.